# Installing netaddr on Python27

Tags: python, plugins, installation

I'm following the installation instructions to install netaddr (https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/installation.html) and unsure as to how to complete the installation.

I have downloaded Python 27, and the netaddr-0.7.10.zip file from https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/downloads and extracted the file to C:\temp\netaddr-0.7.10.

I am then instructed to:

Run the setup file in the root directory like this:

python setup.py install

Can someone please help explain this in a bit more detail for me i.e do I use cmd or python to run the command and do I need to navigate to a particular directory, again how would I navigate to "root" directory?

Sorry I am not used to installing software like this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using 'pip'

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Then the install becomes as simple as running `pip install netaddr` from the command line.

Comment: >>> pip install netaddr
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: According to the Python website it is comes in Python 2.7.9 which I have installed

Comment: The invalid syntax is hitting on the install, not pip if that helps

Comment: This should be irrelevant, but is this Linux, windows or OSx?

Comment: Are you sure you are running from the command line and not the python interpreter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75928/discussion-between-leon-and-c-mac).

Answer (score 1):

or from a debian distro like ubuntu:

```
apt install python-netaddr
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows machine/Cygwin:

```
python -m pip install netaddr
```

upgrading pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```